# Matlab: Animated Line in 3d

Tags: matlab, plot, animated

Let's say I have a nx3 matrix (in this example 100x3), where each column represents the x,y,z coordinate, in some discrete time sample, in 3d. I want to use the animatedLine function to track the coordinate with a maximum of 10 points at a given time. I've been using the Matlab documentation but still stuck on how to do it correctly.

Do I need to pre-define the grid or can Matlab automatically do that given the data? (For this example, the matrix is random, however, in the actual data set, the matrix is known)

```
 A = rand(100, 3)
 x = A(:, 1);
 y = A(:, 2);
 z = A(:, 3);

 grid on;
 h = animatedline('MaximumNumPoints', 10);

for k = 1:length(x)
addpoints(h,x(k),y(k),z(k));
drawnow
end
```

Comment: What is the issue that you are having? Your code seems like it should work just fine with the exception that your `MaximumNumPoints` should probably be 100.

Comment: @Suever My graph is in 2d, and nothing plots. I changed it to 100, still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you have your 3d view on? `view(3)`? Works just fine for me: http://i.imgur.com/LUsv1EV.gif

Comment: @Suever Could you please post your code? I'm not sure why it is not working for me. Thank you!

Comment: Added a formal answer below with the necessary code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you aren't switching to a 3D view and `animatedline` does not alter the view for you automatically. Because of this, you will need to specify the 3D view yourself using `view(3)`.

```
A = rand(100, 3)
x = A(:, 1);
y = A(:, 2);
z = A(:, 3);

grid on;
h = animatedline('MaximumNumPoints', 10);

% Force a 3D view
view(3);

for k = 1:length(x)
    addpoints(h,x(k),y(k),z(k));
    drawnow
end
```

And the result as an animated GIF.

[image]

Comment: I copied and pasted the code. I get the following error:One or more output arguments not assigned during call to "animatedline".

Error in animatedplot (line 8)
h = animatedline('MaximumNumPoints', 10);

Comment: @Sagistic What version of MATLAB?

Comment: I'm using version 2014a

Comment: @Sagistic If you look at the bottom of the `animatedline` documentation, you will see that it was not available in releases before R2014b.

Comment: Thank you! Last question, how do I slow down the animation, it's way too fast.

Comment: @Sagistic You will want to change the `drawnow` to a `pause(t)` where `t` is the pause in seconds.

Comment: Is there a way to get all the points from an animated line plot like the one shown here? I tried `getpoints(h)` but it only returns the last 10 points because `MaximumNumPoints=10`!

Comment: @HarshPurwar `animatedline` will only store the `MaximumNumPoints` because if not, memory usage would grow un-bounded. As a result, you can only retrieve `MaximumNumPoints` from an `animatedline`.